# iPhone image sizing

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, viewport

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around sizing images and ui elements for my iphone app using phonegap (basically mobile website gone native app). Here are my PSD settings:

width: 640px
height: 960px
resolution: 326px

I'm creating two images, one at half resolution and the other at full. Then I'm using a plugin to recognize the retina display and replace all images with "*-2x". The trouble is that the images appear larger on my retina iphone and are blurry. I'm wondering if my viewport is messing things up as it zooms in on the screen to fit the app:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,    user-scalable=no" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used PhoneGap, but to make HTML show images in Retina res what I do is link to a retina res image, say the image is 640x960 pixels, but in the HTML set the size properties to 320x480.

The reason for this, is iOS uses resolution independent "points" instead of "pixels" for layout.

Comment: Can I just size all retina images down by coding "img { width: 50%; height: 50% }" or do have a better way to take care of this on a large scale?

Comment: One last question, do I also need to size non-retina displays down? Is this a product of the viewport method?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You mean size the non-retina images down? You can to save memory, but you don't need to.

Comment: No, I mean do I size all images down or do I target only retina images? Does that make sense?

Comment: You can do either: 1. just use retina res images at the expense of using extra memory on non-retina displays, or 2. create non retina versions for non-retina devices, but then it will be up to you to use the retina or non retina versions conditionally.